# Elastic Beanstalk EC2 give private static ip

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-vpc

I have a Elastic Beanstalk running in a VPC which has access to a 3rd party VPN. The VPN firewall gives access only a single private IP. but every time during a re-deployment the ebs private IP changes in the EC2 instance. is there a way to set a private static ip to ebs ec2 instance

Comment: Usually private IP does not change. What exactly do you do that you gent new private ip for each re-deployment?

Comment: I had to do some changes. it had to redeployed again.